# no module named menu_pool

Tags: python, menu, django-cms

i installed django cms correctly but it says `no module named menu_pool`

do i have to install other menu plugin?

this path `from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool` i cannot find, what is the problem? can someone please help me find the clue

i followed the django-cms docs as written here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3/getting_started/tutorial.html#configuration-and-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much experience with django but you should check the module files installed on your system itself to see if there is some mistake or not.
You can get the directory address from sys.path variable in python itself.
Most of the time source is installed with python modules, so you can open up those files and see for yourself if this module is really there or not.
Or you can use the `dir(menus)` to see what modules are there under menus.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Python can do `import menus` just fine, otherwise the error message would be different. A quick search through the [docs for menus](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concepts/menu_system.html?highlight=menu_pool) reveals that you likely want `MenuPool` instead of your second `menu_pool`.

If I'm not mistaken, `from menus.menu_pool import MenuPool` should give you your expected behavior. Then `MenuPool` will be in your namespace, so you can do `nodes = MenuPool.get_nodes()`, and anything else you wish.